# Short test statements in PL-SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

In SQL server I can print out the value of something with a select statement.

```
SELECT 'xyz'

SELECT GetDate()
```

Can I do something similar in Oracle without adding `FROM <tablename>`?

Comment: No. Oracle always requires the FROM part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the purpose of the **[dual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table)** table. Oracle supplies the Dual in every database and it's accessible, by default, to everyone that connects. It's a single-row, single column table that is useful for testing expressions and pseuducolumns against. Example

```
SELECT 'xyz' from dual;


SQL> select user,sysdate,lower(user) loweruser, 10*1023 from dual;

USER       SYSDATE    LOWERUSER     10*1023
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
NKODNER    22-NOV-11  nkodner         10230
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a `dual` dummy table in Oracle, so try:

```
SELECT GetDate() FROM dual
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You must use DUAL fictious table

To get current system date, you would type

```
SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL
```